# Flexbox container in Chrome doesn't get 100% height

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

Flexbox column container inside another flex container doesn't get 100% height in Chrome, but in Firefox and Edge all ok.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Fotonmoton/pen/LNLVWZ)

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  .inside-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100%;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're missing a `height: 100%` on a parent element: `<header>`

Once you add that in, the layout works in Chrome, as well.

```
header {
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; /* NEW */
}
```

[**Revised Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGZNGr)

When using percentage heights, Chrome requires that each parent element have a defined height. More details here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

When using percentage heights in flexbox, there are rendering differences among the major browsers. More details here:

- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)